# Fourier transform / inverse fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

**Problem statement:** If $F()$ is the Fourier transform of the funciton $f(x)$, then determine $F(f(x-a))$, where $a$ is a constant.

**My attempt:**
$$F() = F(f(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$$
Hence, $$F(f(x-a)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-a)e^{-i\omega x}dx$$
Substituting $x-a = t$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega (t+a)}dt$$
$$= e^{-i\omega a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
$$= e^{-i\omega a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$$
$$= e^{-i\omega a}F() $$

**My teacher's solution:**
$$F() = F(f(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i\omega x}dx$$
Hence, $$F(f(x-a)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-a)e^{i\omega x}dx$$
Substituting $x-a = t$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{i\omega (t+a)}dt$$
$$= e^{i\omega a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt$$
$$= e^{i\omega a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i\omega x}dx$$
$$= e^{i\omega a}F() $$

**The difference between the solutions is the minus sign in the exponent of $e.$**
Which of these is correct? I use the minus sign because that's what the definition of fourier transform gives. Am I wrong? Should I use the minus sign or not? Which solution is correct? And why?

Comment: Yeah one sees both conventions. Sometimes there's a factor of $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ as well.

Comment: It depends on the definition of the Fourier transform. There are many different choices, so in this case I would likely trust the person teaching your class. But maybe read the notes (if there are any)

Comment: @Ali also common is $e^{\pm 2\pi i x\xi }$, or a copy of $1/(2\pi)$, either on $\mathcal F$ or $\mathcal F^{-1}$ (adding for the reader)